# WPF - Text Formatter throws ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

While working with **Text Formatter API** I ran into some problems and need help.

I have a LinkedList of text runs (I've created `Run` class, which has a `Text` property for storing string of text and a bunch of properties, which define text formatting options). I've also implemented my `CustomTextSource` class (derived from `TextSource`). The `GetTextRun` method implementation:

```
public override TextRun GetTextRun(int textSourceCharacterIndex)
    {
        Run run = Document.Runs.ToList().Find(x => x.Contains(textSourceCharacterIndex));
        if (run == null)
        {
            return new TextEndOfParagraph(1);
        }

        if (run.Length == 1 && run.Text.ToString()[0] == '\n')
        {
            return new TextEndOfLine(1);
        }

        return new TextCharacters(run.Text.ToString(),
                run.Start, run.Length,
                new GenericTextRunProperties(run.Formatting));
    }
```

where `Contains` is a method of Run class:

```
public bool Contains(int index)
    {
        return (Start <= index) && ((Start + Length) > index);
    }
```

`Start` and `Length` properties are just integers, that store the beginnig and length of the text run.

The problem is that in some cases the `GetTextRun` method throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` in the last return statement with the message: "*Parameter's value can't be greater than [number]. Parameter's name: offsetToFirstChar*".

For example, when the text store has a character which represents a new line (new line character stores in separate run) and once Text Formatter takes the runwith this character and then tries to take next run (let's call this run "*RunAfterNewLine*") the [number] in the exception message is equals to (*RunAfterNewLine*.Length - 1).

So can anyone explain me why it's happens and how to fix it? 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, `offsetToFirstChar` (where you pass `run.Start`) is

> The offset to the first character to use in characterString.

and `characterString` is the first parameter, where you are passing `run.Text.ToString()`.

Assuming that `run.Text.ToString()` only returns the text in that run and not the whole text of the document, shouldn't you just pass 0?